# Screening due to electron-electron interaction

Tags: condensed-matter

In the random phase approximation we obtain that the Coulomb interaction between charges is replaced by an effective interaction $$V(r)=\frac{1}{r}e^{-k_{D}r}$$ 
In other words, the  electric field only extends over a distance $\frac{1}{k_D}$. If it is a positive charge it is clear, the electron cloud leads to screening, but what does occur when the charge is negative? It seems that in this case there isn't any screening; is it correct that screening occurs only for positive charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I believe that the screening occurs whether the point charge has the same sign, or the opposite sign, to the mobile charge carriers. The derivation of the [screened Coulomb potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric-field_screening) involves solving Poisson's equation in the presence of a perturbing point charge (or charge distribution); either the Debye-Huckel theory or the Thomas-Fermi approximation is used. The result is basically the same, and the screening occurs independently of the sign of the point charge.
The Poisson equation with screening, for a point charge $Q$ at the origin, is
$$
\left[\nabla^2 - k_D^2 \right] V(\mathbf{r}) = 
-\frac{Q}{\varepsilon_0}\delta(\mathbf{r})
$$
and the solution is
$$
V(r) = \frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r} \exp(-k_D r)
$$
irrespective of whether $Q$ is positive or negative.

If you want a physical picture, suppose that we are considering an initially uniform electron gas (you may add a neutralizing, fixed, positive charge distribution too, giving the jellium model, if you wish: the essential point is that it is the electrons that move in response to a perturbation). If we add a positive point charge, we expect the electrons to respond by increasing their density in its neighbourhood, giving the familiar electron cloud or atmosphere. If, instead, we add a *negative* point charge, the electrons respond by *reducing* their density very close to it. You could achieve the same effect by superimposing (on the initial uniform distribution of negative charge) a positively charged atmosphere, having the same form as the electron cloud that we think of surrounding a positive point charge. The effect is due to the way the mobile charges *respond* to the point charge, whatever its sign, and it is always a screening effect.